# Group by main values and 'rest' in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, limit, offset

So I am generating a few graphs from some data within my database.
I would like to have a single query that'll populate my hash like so:

```
=> {1 => 100, 2 => 101, ... 15 => 24, "rest" => 18284}
```

Currently I just limit the results to let's say 15 and do another query with the offset of 15.

```
@first = Sos.order(:hssem).group(:hssem).limit(15).count
@rest = Sos.select(:hssem).offset(15).count
```

Is there a possibility to do that in a single query?

Happy new year by the way - Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can group the Sos rows based on condition

```
.group("case when hssem > 15 then 'other' else hssem end")
```